# After installing ruby 2.2.3 with rbenv it has a different version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to use Rails 5, which requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

I installed 2.2.3 with `rbenv install 2.2.3` and set it global. When I check with `ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]`.

However when I run `bundle exec railties/exe/rails new /parent-folder/api --api --edge` I get the error:

```
Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

You're running
  ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

If I explicitly set the local version to the exact version number `2.2.3p173` or `2.2.3` then it says `rbenv: version '2.2.3' is not installed` (or `2.2.3p173` accordingly).

When I perform `rbenv install -l` to check available versions only `2.2.3` is listed, not the `2.2.3p173`.

Don't understand how to get this to work.

Side notes: I have updated ruby build, my $PATH has rbenv setup correctly, I don't have rvm installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bundle exec railties/exe/rails new /parent-folder/api --api --edge` try `./rails/railties/exe/rails new myapp --edge --dev` where 'rails' is the rails git repo.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I got the error `/Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- thor/group (LoadError)` so I did `gem install thor` and now getting the same error but for `concurrent` which isn't installing easily. It looks like dependencies aren't installed, even though running `bundle install` inside the `rails` directory succeeds. Is there a fix?

Comment: I fixed it combining your solution with deleting the ruby version I had installed, reinstalling bundler and updating system gem files with `gem update --system`. Then when I ran `bundle install` inside the rails directory once more it properly installed all dependencies.